# Can I return to main from recursion without unwinding the stack?

Tags: java, recursion, stack

I have written a recursive method to reduce the length of a string.  If the length of he string in ever less than 20, I want to try the next string in my scanner input.  Is there a way that is more efficient than the way I have coded it?

```
public static void main(String [] args){  
        try { 
            input = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("VectorKnots.txt"));
            output = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("ReduceKnots.txt"));
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("there is a problem with the file");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        while (input.hasNext()){
            loop2 = input.nextLine();
            loop1.delete(0, loop1.length());
            loop1.append(loop2);
            Triangle(loop1);
        }
    }
    public static void Triangle(StringBuilder loop1){
        if (loop1.length() < 20){
            return;
        }
        if (loop1.toString().contains("27")){
            trIndex = loop1.indexOf("27");
            loop1.delete(trIndex, trIndex+1);
            loop1.insert(trIndex, 4);
            Triangle(loop1);
        }
        if (loop1.length() < 20){
            return;
        }
        if (loop1.toString().contains("72")){
            trIndex = loop1.indexOf("72");
            loop1.delete(trIndex, trIndex+1);
            loop1.insert(trIndex, 4);
            Triangle(loop1);
        }
        if (loop1.length() < 20){
            return;
        }
        if (loop1.toString().contains("63")){
            trIndex = loop1.indexOf("63");
            loop1.delete(trIndex, trIndex+1);
            loop1.insert(trIndex, 5);
            Triangle(loop1);
        }
        if (loop1.length() < 20){
            return;
        }
        if (loop1.toString().contains("63")){
            trIndex = loop1.indexOf("63");
            loop1.delete(trIndex, trIndex+1);
            loop1.insert(trIndex, 5);
            Triangle(loop1);
        }
        if (loop1.length() < 20){
            return;
        }
        if (loop1.toString().contains("46")){
            trIndex = loop1.indexOf("46");
            loop1.delete(trIndex, trIndex+1);
            loop1.insert(trIndex, 2);
            Triangle(loop1);
        }
        if (loop1.length() < 20){
            return;
        }
        if (loop1.toString().contains("64")){
            trIndex = loop1.indexOf("64");
            loop1.delete(trIndex, trIndex+1);
            loop1.insert(trIndex, 2);
            Triangle(loop1);
        }
        if (loop1.length() < 20){
            return;
        }
        if (loop1.toString().contains("57")){
            trIndex = loop1.indexOf("57");
            loop1.delete(trIndex, trIndex+1);
            loop1.insert(trIndex, 3);
            Triangle(loop1);
        }
        if (loop1.length() < 20){
            return;
        }
        if (loop1.toString().contains("75")){
            trIndex = loop1.indexOf("75");
            loop1.delete(trIndex, trIndex+1);
            loop1.insert(trIndex, 3);
            Triangle(loop1);
        }
        if (loop1.length() < 20){
            return;
        }
        if (loop1.toString().contains("52")){
            trIndex = loop1.indexOf("52");
            loop1.delete(trIndex, trIndex+1);
            loop1.insert(trIndex, 6);
            Triangle(loop1);
        }
        if (loop1.length() < 20){
            return;
        }
        if (loop1.toString().contains("25")){
            trIndex = loop1.indexOf("25");
            loop1.delete(trIndex, trIndex+1);
            loop1.insert(trIndex, 6);
            Triangle(loop1);
        }
        if (loop1.length() < 20){
            return;
        }
        if (loop1.toString().contains("34")){
            trIndex = loop1.indexOf("34");
            loop1.delete(trIndex, trIndex+1);
            loop1.insert(trIndex, 7);
            Triangle(loop1);
        }
        if (loop1.length() < 20){
            return;
        }
        if (loop1.toString().contains("43")){
            trIndex = loop1.indexOf("43");
            loop1.delete(trIndex, trIndex+1);
            loop1.insert(trIndex, 7);
            Triangle(loop1);
        }
        if (loop1.length() < 20){
            return;
        }
        if (loop1.toString().contains("1") && loop1.indexOf("1") + 2) == 0){
            trIndex = loop1.indexOf("1");
            loop1.delete(trIndex);
            loop1.delete(trIndex + 1);
            Triangle(loop1);
        }
        if (loop1.length() < 20){
            return;
        }
        if (loop1.toString().contains("0") && loop1.indexOf("1") + 2) == 1){
            trIndex = loop1.indexOf("0");
            loop1.delete(trIndex);
            loop1.delete(trIndex + 1);
            Triangle(loop1);
        }
        if (loop1.length() < 20){
            return;
        }
        if (loop1.length() > 19){
            out.println(loop1);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't name methods starting with a capital letter.

Comment: You probably want to rewrite `Triangle` to use a loop.

Comment: A technique I use in such case is abusing the `try`-`catch` mechanism.

Comment: Java does not support tail recursion, so the answer to your question is 'No'.

Comment: @izaakberg: you mean performance-wise or code-wise?

Comment: Furthermore what do you try to achieve here? I think you are scanning the `String(Builder)` way too much, you can probably do this way more efficient...

Comment: I have a list of vector additions that describe a closed loop in space.  If the length of these can be reduced to less than 20, I know that they have a specific quality I am looking for.  A rough estimate of the number I have to check is 10 trillion.  I figure this is going to take some time to run, and was thinking if I could return to main once the length was less than 20, I might save some time.

Answer (score 0):

You won't need to return from deeply nested recursion if you use iteration instead.  Try:

```
public static void triangle(StringBuilder loop1) {
    for (;;) {
        if (loop1.length() < 20)
            return; 
        int trIndex = loop1.indexOf("27");
        if ( trIndex >= 0 ) {
            loop1.delete(trIndex+1);
            loop1.setCharAt(trIndex,'2');
            continue;   // start over using loop instead of recursion
        }

        trIndex = loop1.indexOf("72");
        if ( trIndex >= 0 ) {
            loop1.delete(trIndex+1);
            loop1.setCharAt(trIndex,'7');
            continue;   // start over using loop instead of recursion
        }

        // more cases

        break;
    }
}
```

Also note that

1. Your test at the end: `if ( ... > 19 ) out.println(loop1)` won't do anything because you have an `if ( ... < 20 ) return;` just prior; probably want to move the printline into `main ()`
2. contains () simply does indexOf () >= 0, so you might as well do that alone instead of both.
3. StringBuilder.insert(loc,int) converts the int to string, then runs the string version of StringBuilder.insert; so why not just feed it a string right off instead.
4. You might consider building some kind of automaton, perhaps something that looks at each character in the string only once.

Comment: I've never seen continue before, I will try that.

Comment: The if( ... > 19) is at the end because I only want to check if the loop is greater than 19 characters if no further possible reductions can be made.  With that in mind, isn't that line in the correct spot?

Comment: Ok, perhaps your right.  My point (though poorly expressed above) was, if the flow of control reaches that > 19 test, you will also know at that point that the length is >= 20, so you don't need to test for > 19.